# Why we create Entity/Enquiry.php And Form/EnquiryType.php In Seperate Folders Symfony2?

Tags: symfony

Going through the [Symblog tutorial](http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/validators-and-forms.html) of Symfony2, While creating forms I came to a point where in I create Contact Entity (Entity/Enquiry.php) where I define some fields and some methods to access these fields. Then I create another folder Form/EnquiryType.php to build the form and then a contact.html.twig to display. I am unable to understand why we created 2 namespaces for  Entity/Enquiry.php and Form/EnquiryType.php. when they have to deal with each other. Why dont we wrote both the classes within one folder or one file. And one more question. Do they belong to Controller or View part of MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form types are here to configure how data coming from objects (like Entities) are mapped to a form (and vice/versa).

Entities should'nt be named "entities", they should be just your buisness objects, that can be persisted through a layer called doctrine2.

To answer you on separation of concerns, 
Entities are about M,
while form Types are about user inputs (so the VC).
View because it render a human interface to let user enter input,
Controller because that's where you handle the form lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is logical separation. Why don't we define all parts of MVC in one folder/namespace? Because it will be a mess. That's why logical separation is needed.

And not all entities have to have related form types — using entities without forms is normal.

Comment: Thanks for ur response, What does entity mean here, like in form folder i can understand we ll be having forms in it. what does entity folder represent

Comment: [On entities](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/architecture.html#entities).